# Java Text File comparison - Excess and Missing

Tags: java, file, comparison

I have a requirement to compare 2 text files (`MasterCopy.txt` and `ClientCopy.txt)`. I would like to get the list of strings which are missing in ClientCopy.txt. Also need to get the list of strings which are in excess.

Contents of MasterCopy.txt

- London
- Paris
- Rome

Contents of ClientCopy.txt

- London
- Berlin
- Rome
- Amsterdam

I would like to get these results

**Missing:**

- Paris

**Excess:**

- Berlin
- Amsterdam

Comment: How large are your files? What have you already tried?

Comment: This question, in its current form, is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. SO is mainly meant to help with debugging existing code. This question is asking for SO users to effectively write the code for you. What have you tried so far? What isn't working yet? Post some of your code and someone can help you debug and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ideas that come to mind are getting the diff of the two files:

https://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/

From their wiki

> Task 1: Compute the difference between to files and print its deltas
>   Solution:
>
> ```
> import difflib.*;
> public class BasicJavaApp_Task1 {
>   // Helper method for get the file content
>   private static List<String> fileToLines(String filename) {
>     List<String> lines = new LinkedList<String>();
>     String line = "";
>     try {
>       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
>       while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
>         lines.add(line);
>       }
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>       e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>     return lines;
>   }
>
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>     List<String> original = fileToLines("originalFile.txt");
>     List<String> revised  = fileToLines("revisedFile.xt");
>
>     // Compute diff. Get the Patch object. Patch is the container for computed deltas.
>     Patch patch = DiffUtils.diff(original, revised);
>
>     for (Delta delta: patch.getDeltas()) {
>       System.out.println(delta);
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

or to use a HashSet:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

Modification of @Nic's answer to use HashSet:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(“MasterCopy.txt”));
HashSet<String> masterlist = new HashSet<String>();
while (s.hasNext()){
  masterlist.put(s.next());
}
s.close();
s = new Scanner(new File(“ClientCopy.txt”));
HashSet<String> clientlist = new HashSet<String>();
while (s.hasNext()){
  clientlist.put(s.next());
}
s.close();

//Do the comparison
ArrayList<String> missing = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> excess = new ArrayList<String>();
//Check for missing or excess
for(String line : masterlist){
    if(clientlist.get(line) == null) missing.add(line);
}
for(String line : clientlist){
    if(masterlist.get(line) == null) excess.add(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If execution time is not a big factor you can do this, assuming you are only comparing each line:

```
//Get the files into lists
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(“MasterCopy.txt”));
HashSet<String> masterlist = new HashSet<String>();
while (s.hasNext()){
    masterlist.add(s.next());
}
s.close();
s = new Scanner(new File(“ClientCopy.txt”));
HashSet<String> clientlist = new HashSet<String>();
while (s.hasNext()){
    clientlist.add(s.next());
}
s.close();

//Do the comparison
HashSet<String> missing = new HashSet<String>();
HashSet<String> excess = new HashSet<String>();
//Check for missing or excess
for(String s : masterlist){
    if(!clientlist.contains(s)) missing.add(s);
}
for(String s : clientlist){
    if(!masterlist.contains(s)) excess.add(s);
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that HashSet would be most beneficial because the lookup time of a string is O(1) and because the memory size of the array is based on the hash function and number of elements, not the length of the string being stored.

Comment: Edited to use HashSets.

Comment: @Zoro If it works please mark this as the selected answer. :)